# Как дописать текст в конце названия файла?

Tags: php

Есть файл text.txt.(который загружаю в папку) Наверно есть какая то функция которая позволит в конце имени text дописать какой то небольшой рамдомный текст по времени например.

Answer (score 1):

```
$file= '/files/text.txt';

$hash = md5(time().rand(11111111,99999999));

$path = pathinfo($file);

$new = $path['dirname'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$new .= $path['filename'].$hash.$path['extension'];

rename($file, $new);
```